# How to print without formatting in bash?

Tags: bash

```
printf "-Xdebug"
```

Gives:

```
bash: printf: -X: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
```

`echo -n "-Xdebug"` works but according to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11193466/1345655) it isn't portable.

> There are multiple versions of the echo command, with different
>   behaviors. Apparently the shell used for your script uses a version
>   that doesn't recognize -n.

How can I have a string be printed to screen uninterpreted, as is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a format string

```
printf '%s' '-Xdebug'
```

Or use `--` to signal end of option processing

```
printf -- '-Xdebug'
```

Comment: The `%s` solution is much safer in general — `printf -- ` *`string`* will mangle strings that contain `%` or ``\``.

Answer (score -2):

```
echo '-Xdebug' > /dev/lpr
```

It will send the text -Xdebug to the line printer, your default printer.
An alternative would be to format it first, with the program `fmt`:

```
echo '-Xdebug' | fmt > /dev/lpr
```

Comment: 'Print' just means display on the screen in this context.  The problem is about trying to use `printf` when the text to print starts with a minus, which is being treated as an option instead of text.